# Accessing collectionView cells visible/invisible

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, didselectrowatindexpath

I got a function to flip my collection view cells, which is working fine. My problem is that I want to flip all the cells and not just this one visible cell, so when I swipe to next cell it will be flipped.

This is what I am using to flip the one visible cell only. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
func flipAction() {
        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: mainCollecView.contentOffset, size: mainCollecView.bounds.size)
        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
        let visibleIndexPath = mainCollecView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
        let cell = mainCollecView.cellForItem(at: visibleIndexPath!) as! MainCollectionViewCell

if cell.isFlipped == false {
       //Flip card
        cell.flip()
        cell.isFlipped = true
        flipBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "reversed"), for: .normal)

    } else {
        // Flip the card back
        flipBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "Calendar"), for: .normal)
        cell.flipBack()
        cell.isFlipped = false
    }
   }
```

Comment: Complete an array form all cells with like var myarr = Array<Bool>  for isFlipped values. Then if myarr[indexPath ... ] cell...

Comment: @user3344236, thanks for your response. I am new to swift, can you give an example please... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approaches. But if you want all to be flipped, use a variable in you  Class, like

```
      var isFlipped:Bool = false
```

Inside your function now:

```
      flipAction() {
           isfliped =  !isfliped
           mycollection.reload() //where mycollection is yours 
      }
```

Then inside  your

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
     {
       if isfliped == false {
             // your code for cell when is not flipped 
       } else  {
             //your code for cell when is flipped
       }
```

This way all cells will be flipped or not at once, not depending if they are visible or not.

Comment: thanks for your response. You solution wont work, because I am using the flip method inside a button and not the collectionViewcellForItemAt.

Comment: No matter there you call it, it sets a value declared generic and your collection view reloads based on that value.